# change size of rectangle after object detection

Tags: c++, opencv, rectangles

I use below code for object detection.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
VideoCapture cap(0); 
if (!cap.isOpened()){
    cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
    return -1;}
int totalFrameNumber = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
Mat frame;
namedWindow("MyVideo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while (1)
{
    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
        break;
    }
Mat frame2;

Rect rectangle2(420,280, 40, 40);
rectangle(frame, rectangle2, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
Mat cornerstrength;
    cornerHarris(frame, cornerstrength, 3, 3, 0.1);
    //threshold the corner strength
    Mat harriscorners;
    double th = 0.00001;
    threshold(cornerstrength, harriscorners, th, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    morphologyEx(harriscorners, harriscorners, MORPH_CLOSE, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 6);
    //local maxima detection
    Mat dilated, localMax;
    dilate(cornerstrength, dilated, Mat());
    compare(cornerstrength, dilated, localMax, CMP_EQ);
    threshold(cornerstrength, harriscorners, th, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    harriscorners.convertTo(harriscorners, CV_8U);
    bitwise_and(harriscorners, localMax, harriscorners);
    harriscorners.convertTo(harriscorners, CV_32F);
    Mat S(0, 2, CV_32SC1);

    //drawing a circle around corners

    for (int j = 0;j < harriscorners.rows;j++)
        for (int i = 0;i < harriscorners.cols;i++)
        {

            if (harriscorners.at<float>(j, i)> 0)
            {    circle(frame, Point(i, j), 5, Scalar(255), 2, 8);
                Mat pt(1, 2, CV_32SC1);
                pt.at<int>(1, 0) = i;
                pt.at<int>(0, 1) = j;
                // Add the point to S
                S.push_back(pt);
                for (int x = 430; x < 460; x++)
                    for (int y = 285; y < 315; y++)
                        if  ((pt.at<int>(1, 0) = i) == x && (pt.at<int>(0, 1) = j) == y))


                        {
                            Rect rectangle2(430, 285, 30,30);}}}
imshow("MyVideo", frame);
if (waitKey(30) == 27)
                {
                    cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

I want When the condition **if  ((pt.at(1, 0) = i) == x && (pt.at(0, 1) = j) == y))** is established then the size of rectangle2 from 
**rectangle2(420,280,40,40)** Change to **rectangle2(430,285,30,30)**.I can do this change but when I use my code Both rectangle(previous rectangle2 and new rectangle2)are displayed in picture.but I want to display onle new rectangle2.do you have any idea to solve my problem? thanks a lot..

Comment: the code is incomplete, but I see one error, `frame2` is created but not initialized. I see also that you use frame to draw a rectangle on it, you should save a `clone()` of it before painting on it. If not it will always have the rectangles you draw on it.

Comment: frame2 was a  Typographical mistakes.I use Mat f = frame.clone() for save frame before draw rectangle.but what can I do for draw only new rectangle after that loop?

Comment: before that loop  I want to draw (420,280,40,40) and after that loop I want to draw (430,285,30,30).

Comment: use a clone of frame, do the rectangle to this clone, do whatever else you need to this clone, and then when you want to change the rectangle, clone again frame and draw the rectangle to this second clone

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments, you need to create a clone and keep frame almost a constant.

So, in this part:

```
    Rect rectangle2(420,280, 40, 40);
    rectangle(frame, rectangle2, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    Mat cornerstrength;
    cornerHarris(frame, cornerstrength, 3, 3, 0.1);
```

Write something more like this

```
    cv::Mat frameCopy = frame.clone();
    Rect rectangle2(420,280, 40, 40);
    rectangle(frameCopy , rectangle2, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    Mat cornerstrength;
    cornerHarris(frameCopy , cornerstrength, 3, 3, 0.1);
```

Then, in this part, I am not sure what it is intended to do

```
                for (int x = 430; x < 460; x++)
                    for (int y = 285; y < 315; y++)
                        if  ((pt.at<int>(1, 0) = i) == x && (pt.at<int>(0, 1) = j) == y))    
                        {
                            Rect rectangle2(430, 285, 30,30);
                        }
             }
         }
                            imshow("MyVideo", frame);
```

But probably you want to show the new image with a new rectangle, so You can do something like before again:

```
    cv::Mat anotherCopy= frame.clone();
    Rect rectangleInLoop(430,280,30,30);
    rectangle(anotherCopy, rectangleInLoop, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    imshow("MyVideo", anotherCopy);
```

Comment: thanks for you'r help api55.but,Where do I add the last part to the code?and my problem exactlly is when an object it placed in (420,280,40,40) than the size of rectangle change to (430,280,30,30) and  only show up (430,280,30,30) in my picture.

Comment: @louis89 sorry I updated with the new numbers, it is not clear what the for loops are for since you only create rectangle (which is only valid at that scope) so I remove the for from the code to make it clear, basically, the answer is, do not change frame, only a copy of it, look when I do `clone`

Comment: @louis89 I recommend to create a new question about it. If this one solved the current problem, you should accept the answer and up voted so people know this solution works for this kind of problem. Creating a new question about the adaptive threshold will help people find a solution to their problem easier.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't draw both rectangle in a window.but thanks for your help api55

Comment: @louis89 you asked to not draw both rectangles in the same windows.... my answer is for that, to draw them both in the same window then just use the same frame in the function rectangle, it should show both

Comment: I said that I want to show rectangle(420,280,40,40) in my frame and  when an object placed in (420,280,40,40) then the size of rectangle change to (430,280,30,30) and show up rectangle(430,280,30,30) in  my frame.your code can change the size of rectangle but can't show up rectangle(420,280,40,40) at first and then show up rectangle(430,280,30,30)

Comment: just with an imshow after drawing the first rectangle is enough to do that job (using the code I gave you). But with a waitKey of 30 it will be quite faste the change, also, since you have it inside a loop it will show 30 ms the image with one rectangle and 30 ms the image with the other rectangle.

Comment: I imsow frame or  frameCopy or anotherCopy?